# How to send user health data to server periodically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, fetch, healthkit

I'm trying to make an application, which collects user data from HealthKit and CMMotionActivities from CoreMotion and sends it to server. Since CoreMotion contains a lot of CMMotionActivity records, I'm trying to reduce data size and share it with server as often as possible.

I have implemented data reporting with background fetch:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //other stuff
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    profile.loadUserProfile { (result) in
        result.ifSuccess {
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }
        result.ifFailure {
            completionHandler(.failed)
        }
    }
}

func loadUserProfile(completion: @escaping (Result<Any>)->Void) {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    loadUserHealthProfile() // load health data and dispatchGroup.leave()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    loadUserMotionProfile() // load motion data and dispatchGroup.leave()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [unowned self] in
        self.networkingClient.report(model: self.userProfile.userData) { result in
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Despite it works, I'm not sure, if this solution is correct. As I see in Apple documentation, background fetch is intended to download updates to application, I use it vise versa. Is there a proper way to share user health&motion data with server?

**UPD**

It doesn't work as expected, application.isProtectedDataAvailable is `true` while devise is locked, and I can't query HealthKit data. Is the only case for application to send data is when fetch triggered while user interacts with iPhone?